# shell script to send ARP table

Tags: linux, arp

I use the following script to query for the ARP table. However, I only want to execute this script when the ARP table changes instead of periodically (cron job). How can I achieve this? Also can the command below keep the ARP table on server updated?

```
arp | grep -v 'incomplete' | tail
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

I found the `ip(8)` command in the `iproute2` package does exactly what you want!  `CONFIG_ARPD` turned out to be irrelevant to this (it was even removed from the kernel at Linux 3.12.)

Run `ip monitor neigh` and watch its output.

But I felt the ARP table is changed rather frequently... (cf. [Configuring ARP age timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372011/configuring-arp-age-timeout) )

Anyways please disregard my old answer below.

### Old answer

I think your Linux kernel must have the `CONFIG_ARPD` option enabled (try `grep CONFIG_ARPD /boot/config-*`) to support such operations.  And if so, you need to write C program to receive the information.

Comment: yes, it does have such config. How then can i send the information  when the arp table changes?

Comment: I found `ip monitor neigh` does the job.  Please see my updated answer.